# Values being warped

Tags: c#

For some reason when i output Best in this program it blows up what the ints number should be. it hard to understand what the ints real number is!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Safr_Manager
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {



            var sortarry = new[] {'4', '6', '4', '7', '8', '3'};

            int best = -1;




            for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
            {
                var cursel = sortarry[i];
                if (cursel > best)
                {

                    best = cursel;

                }



                Console.WriteLine(cursel);
                Console.WriteLine(best);



            }



        }

    }
}
```

And this is what it outputs. You can see how it changes what it should be in the Current best part!

```
Current selected: 4
Current best: 52
Current selected: 6
Current best: 54
Current selected: 4
Current best: 54
Current selected: 7
Current best: 55
Current selected: 8
Current best: 56
Current selected: 3
Current best: 56
```

Comment: 52 means value of char '4', remove single quote from array

Comment: or `Console.WriteLine(Char.GetNumericValue(best).ToString());`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using quotes around a number eg. '4' tells c# it's a char. If you implicitly convert that to an int, it uses the ASCII code of that char (eg. 52). In order to use the ints, set your array up like this:

```
var sortarry = new[] {4, 6, 4, 7, 8, 3};
```

Answer (score 1):

you are comparing int with char. Not a good idea if you want to compare the value. 
So change your array to int.

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var sortarry = new[] {4, 6, 4, 7, 8, 3};

            int best = -1;
            for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
            {
                var cursel = sortarry[i];
                if (cursel > best)
                {

                    best = cursel;

                }
                Console.WriteLine(cursel);
                Console.WriteLine(best);
            }

    }
}
```

Code example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/hjlYjU

Comment: Also you don't have to specify 6 in for cycle. just use `sortarry.Length`